# Google Maps disable prefetcher service

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, cyanogenmod, google-maps

I have a Motorola Cliq, running Cyanogenmod 7.2. I've cached my local area as an offline map and would like to disable or stop the PrefetcherService that sol runs all the time on wifi. I can't find an option to do this in Google maps.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I'd love an answer to this question. My Pos^W phone has so little memory that foreground apps are constantly being killed and I miss incoming calls because the system slows down to such a crawl that the call has gone to voicemail by the time Phone has clawed its way back into memory, yet somehow this entirely useless service is always running every time I check, despite the ram shortage.